# Can't start the delayed_jobs process

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

I am having problems getting delayed_job to restart.

When I login and run rake `delayed_job RAILS_ENV=production` everything works fine and all the jobs are processed, however if run `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job restart` a new process is started, but none of the jobs are processed.

**Update**: I should also mention that I can run both of the above commands on my dev machine and in both cases all the delayed jobs are processed properly.

**Update**: I removed the previous update since it was in regards to running the script from my machine, but since I can't get delayed_jobs to process the tasks when calling the command on the server, there is no use in making things even more complex.

**Update**: Earlier I mentioned that running `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job restart` started a process, but didn't do any processing.  It turns out that, even though a pid is displayed after running the command, no process matches the pid or is there any additional ruby processes running. Below is the content of the script/delayed_job file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

I am using delayed_jobs v2.0.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to one of the responses to [Terminal says delayed_job starting, but not doing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444736/terminal-says-delayed-job-starting-but-not-doing-anything) there is an issue with the daemon gem v1.1.0.  After installing v.1.0.10 it works fine. The reason it was working on my dev machine is I had that 1.0.10 version already installed.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, you need to pass the environment as parameter to the script. There's some quirk in the script handling environment variables correctly:

```
ruby script/delayed_job -e production restart
```

Comment: I gave that a go with no luck.  However I did notice that it was having problems loading the rails 2.3.8 gem.  See the updates in the original post for those details.

Comment: Check your .gemrc file on the machine producing this error... Maybe there're any search pathes set?

Comment: According to https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/7 setting the environment via the -e param is no longer supported, unless there was a later fix for this issue.

Comment: @chris Oh well, I've looked at an old project where I used this. Will be fun rewriting all those capistrano tasks when updating delayed_job... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems getting any delayed_job daemon to start. I traced it back to a permissions problem. If you are using a deploying user, be sure to the script/delayed_job and the log directory writable for that user. Or, modify your /etc/group to give that user permission to the assigned group on those files.

My environment:
ruby (ree-1.8.7-2012.02)
rails (3.2.6)
delayed_job (3.0.3)
delayed_job_active_record (0.3.2)
daemons (1.1.8)

Answer (score 0):

If this is on your production machine, make sure that you have permissions to access the tmp/pids folder. Without it, you wont be able to create any daemons.